# Функция для создания событий для элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется такой код

```
document.querySelector('.tabs-tile').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        let oTarget = ev.target.closest('.list-item');
        this.setAttribute('id', oTarget.getAttribute('id'));
        this.setAttribute('data', oTarget.getAttribute('data'));
        [...this.querySelectorAll('.list-item')].forEach(function(el) {
            el.style.backgroundColor = '';
        });
        oTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#fa0';
    });
```

Данный скрипт работает с элементом класса .tabs-tile. Как сделать, что бы работало и с другими классами?
Как вариант сделать через функцию, например:

```
fun('.tabs-tile');
fun('classA');
fun('classB');
```

Но не знаю как такую функцию сделать

Comment: И в чем проблема окружить код функцией и ее аргумент установить в параметр querySelector, собственно вы уже все и написали

Comment: проблема в том, что не работает, не может прочитать свойства addEventListener

Comment: так это не проблема, если элемент не найден, то querySelector вернет `null`, проверяйте элемент, возможно класс с ошибкой задан(например точку забыли), а далее уже применяйте addEventListener